# Как авторизоватся и получить любую страницу из сайта на python?

Tags: python

У меня вот такой код для авторизации. Но мне два раза выдает тот же *html*, а нужно чтобы сначало выдало страницу авторизации, а потом ту которую запрашиваю.Как же это разрулить? Все дело в куках я так понимаю.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


EMAIL = '***'
PASSWORD = '***'


def login(url):
    values = {'email': EMAIL,
              'password': PASSWORD
             }
    page = requests.post(url, data=values)
    print(page.content)


def get_html(url):
    responce = requests.get(url)
    return responce.content

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


def main():
    print(login('http://***.**.***.**'))
    if login('http://***.**.***.**'):
        print(get_html('http://***.**.***.**'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Создайте объект сессии: `session = requests.Session()` и везде обращайтесь к нему, то есть вместо `requests.get` пишите `session.get`

Comment: Если вас повторно перебрасывает на туже страницу, то вероятнее всего вы неправильно пытаетесь авторизоваться. Трудно, по данным которые вы приложили, дать точный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, как подсказывают комментарии, создайте объект сессии:

```
def main():
    session = requests.Session()
```

Его передавайте дальше:

```
    if login('http://...', session):
```

В функции login нужно проверить успешно ли прошла авторизация. Можно коду ответа:

```
def login(url, session):
    values = {'email': EMAIL,
              'password': PASSWORD
             }
    page = session.post(url, data=values)
    print(page.content)
    return page.status_code == 200
```

И в main добавим else:

```
    if login('http://...'):
        print(get_html('http://...', session))
    else:
        print('authorization failed')
```

Потому что скорее всего проблема в ней. А как сделать нормальную авторизацию - нужно смотреть как она устроена на конкретном сайте

Comment: лучше чекать через `page.raise_for_status()`